# Remove beginning part of a string from column data

Tags: string, excel

I have an excel file in which there are 10 columns with the data starting from:

```
Text1 | Text4 | Text7
Text2 | Text5 | Text8
Text3 | Text6 | Text9
```

For my requirement, I have to remove the part `Text` from all these cells. How is this done in Excel? I am a complete newbie to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly with your data without formula

**Manually**

- Select the area of interest
- Press Ctrl & F to bring up the Find and Replace dialog
- Select the ‘Replace’ tab
- Under ‘Find what’ put `Text`, leave ‘Replace With’ blank
- Ensure ‘Match entire cell content’ is unchecked

[image: sample]

**VBA**

`Selection.Replace "Text", vbNullString, xlPart`

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Text",""))
```

Comment: I tried this formula: `= INT((SUBSTITUTE(G2, "Text", ""))` but I start getting this `circular reference warning` and a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first cell is A1
type this in the formula bar 
= Mid(A1, 5, Len(A1) -4)
you can fill series for the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

Find and replace tool works well, if the "text" varies though it will no longer work. For future people looking for a fix for a similar problem but where the text is different then you just place " *" in the find what box then replace. (don't use the quote marks but do put in a space before the *)

This removes any entry after the text. swapping the * and the space will remove any text before the space.